# Counting distinct values across columns using sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, count, distinct

I'm trying to count distinct values across columns using sqlite3 in python but cant seem to get the correct results. Am only able to get the count of distinct values in 1 column.

I've create a database and imported the csv file as a table

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
curr = conn.cursor()

curr.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test')
curr.execute('CREATE TABLE social_table (from_id INTEGER, to_id INTEGER)')
conn.commit()

with open ('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)

    for row in reader:
        from_id = row[0]
        to_id = row[1]

        curr.execute('INSERT INTO test (from_id, to_id) VALUES (?, ?)',
                    (from_id, to_id))
    conn.commit()
```

| from_id | to_id |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 6 |
| 0 | 7 |
| 0 | 8 |
| 0 | 10 |
| 0 | 11 |

The unique users in this table across columns should be 11 but my code

```
curr.execute("Select Count(*) from (Select DISTINCT from_id, to_id from test)")
```

gives me 10 instead.

Anyone able to help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your query is not correct, instead try this:

```
curr.execute("""
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
    FROM (
        SELECT from_id as user_id FROM social_table 
        UNION 
        SELECT to_id as user_id FROM social_table
    )
""")
```

Just select all distinct values of `from_id` and then unioning them with all distinct values of `to_id`, then count the number of distinct values in this unioned set, which should give you the total number of unique users across both columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should be counting distinct users from *both* the `from_id` and `to_id` columns.  We can use a union for this purpose:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT from_id AS id FROM social_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_id FROM social_table
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

another idea is to concat the columns a string

```
from_id || '-' || to_id
```

So you query will be

```
curr.execute("Select Count(*) from (Select DISTINCT from_id || '-' || to_id  from social_table)")
```

Comment: This does not work: https://dbfiddle.uk/G5gbbpPk

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `from_id` and `to_id` should not be nullable, so you should correct the table definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE social_table (from_id INTEGER NOT NULL, to_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

In this case, instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` which is less efficient you should use a simple `COUNT(*)`:

```
sql = """
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
    FROM (
      SELECT from_id FROM social_table 
      UNION 
      SELECT to_id FROM social_table
    )
"""
curr.execute(sql)
```

because [`UNION`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound_select_statements) removes duplicates from the resultset.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/u2XDKNoB).